# react / redux - How to dispatch an action on componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to dispatch an action on my ComponentDidMount, but it never works.

The situation is:
I've created a function to switch language on a reducer, who initialize the language to the browser language. And I want to change the language to the first language available on my API when I call my component.

I tried a lot of things from StackOverflow and I don't understand why when I put my function on the render (onClick, onScroll) it works fine, but on my componentDidMount, it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
import {switchLanguage} from '../actions/langs'

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      langs: langs
    };

    let switchLanguage = this.props.switchLanguage;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    switchLanguage(1, 'fr')
  }

  render() {
    [...]
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {langId: state.languageReducer.id, language: state.languageReducer.language}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    switchLanguage: (id, lang) => dispatch(switchLanguage(id, lang))
  }
}

Header = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);

export default injectIntl(Header);
```

I'm new on Redux, I just follow the redux tutorial to do this.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should call `this.props.switchLanguage(1, 'fr')` on your `componentDidMount`

Comment: I thought I had already tried but apparently no. It works, you're my hero! thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

this line in your constructor

```
let switchLanguage = this.props.switchLanguage;
```

does nothing, because a variable declared with `let` "dies" at the end of the `constructor() { }` statement. You have to call it this way:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.switchLanguage(1, 'fr')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the name `mapDispatchToProps`.

If you look into the definition of `mapDispatchToProps` , `switchLanguage` ( the key ) is a function that calls dispatch ( it dispatches something ).

Since you are mapping this `...ToProps`, it only makes sense that you will find the function that calls dispatch in `props`.

Therefore, `this.props.switchLanguage`, with whatever arguments you need.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you have this `let switchLanguage = this.props.switchLanguage;` but problem is your `this.props.switchLanguage` doesn't accept any parameters, and when you try to invoke in `componentDidMount`, you tried to pass in parameters `switchLanguage(1, 'fr')` which of course not working.

Instead, you can directly call the method in your `componentDidMount()` as below, and remove the declaration of method in your constructor

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.props.switchLanguage(1, 'fr');
}
```